# Codacy secure error

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, codacy

Codacy js test give me an secure errors:

> Function Call Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection)

For next code row:

```
let computedType = window.getComputedStyle(arr[i]).display.toString();
```

Why can't i use `[i]` for working with loop and why it is not secure?

Comment: See https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/14/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation/

Comment: [eslint-plugin-security](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security): "*This project […] finds a lot of false positives*".